# Get td value of the table for each tr

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath, html-parsing

How can I extract the internal values ​​to the `td` for each `tr` in a table using the `DOM`? I have a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="rowData">
         <td class="cellData">
            <a href="#"><span> DATA 1 </span></a>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 1 a </div></div>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 1 b </div></div>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 1 c </div></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowData">
         <td class="cellData">
            <a href="#"><span> DATA 2 </span></a>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 2 a </div></div>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 2 b </div></div>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 2 c </div></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowData">
         <td class="cellData">
            <a href="#"><span> DATA 3 </span></a>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 3 a </div></div>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 3 b </div></div>
         </td>
         <td class="cellData">
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"> DATA 3 c </div></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
<table>
```

What I would get is: for each row

```
<label> DATA n </label>
<input value="DATA n a">
<input value="DATA n b">
<input value="DATA n c">
```

I was stuck with this code:

```
$html = file_get_contents($link);
$html2 = (preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $html));
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html2);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach($xpath->query('.//tbody/tr[@class="rowData"]') as $node){
}
foreach($xpath->query('.//tbody/tr/td/div/div[@class="div2"]') as $node){
}
foreach($xpath->query('.//tbody/tr/td/a/span') as $node){
echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess the code is sufficiently self-explaining. XPath used three times: for finding all table rows, fetching the label, and fetching all input values.

```
foreach($xpath->query('.//tbody/tr[@class="rowData"]') as $row) {
    echo '<label>'.$xpath->query('td[1]/a/span', $row)->item(0)->textContent."</label>\n";
    foreach($xpath->query('td[position() > 1]/div/div', $row) as $col) {
        echo '<input value="'.trim($col->textContent).'" />'."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, I had to fix the <label>, gave me problems "Trying to get property of non-object". but I solved it by adding a small change

$i=0;
foreach($xpath->query('.//tbody/tr[@class="rowData"]') as $row) {
 $count=$i++;
    echo '<label>'.$xpath->query('.//tbody/tr/td/a/span')->item($count)->textContent."</label>\n";
    foreach($xpath->query('td[position() > 1]/div/div', $row) as $col) {
        echo '<input value="'.trim($col->textContent).'" />';
    }
 echo "<br>";
}

Comment: This is really weird, especially as the second XPath query constructed exactly the same way works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution, actually two - but commented one is too ugly. :)

```
$html = file_get_contents($link);
$html2 = (preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $html));
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html2);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach($elements as $node){

$inputs1=$node->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(1); // 0,2,4...does same
$inputs2=$node->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(3);
$inputs3=$node->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(5);

echo '<label>'. $node->firstChild->nodeValue.  '</label>';
echo '<input value="'. $inputs1->nodeValue.  '">';
echo '<input value="'. $inputs2->nodeValue.  '">';
echo '<input value="'. $inputs3->nodeValue.  '">';

//ugly as hell - but it is working :)

/*echo '<input value="'. $node->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue.  '">';


echo '<input value="'. $node->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue.  '">';

echo '<input value="'. $node->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue.  '">';*/

echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help with this code :) but I had some problems, the third cell appeared empty, I solved with the solution proposed Jens Erat and 2 with minor changes it works. but thank you for the time you have spent on solving :)

Comment: Np, better solution is accepted, for sure. :) But, how third cell appeared empty... On same html/table structure?